# How can one run multiple programs in the background with single command?

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can one run multiple programs in the background with single command?

I have tried the commands below, but they do not work.

```
nohup ./script1.sh & && nohup ./script2.sh &
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '&&'

nohup ./script1.sh & ; nohup ./script2.sh &
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'
```

Comment: what is a single "command"? A line of bash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612371/how-do-i-run-multiple-background-commands-in-bash-in-a-single-line

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but && implies knowing the exit code of the previous command. If you background it, the exit code won't be known. What was the functional need there?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From a shell syntax point of view, `&` separates commands like `;`/`|`/`&&`... (though of course with different semantic). So it's just:

```
cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3 &
```

Comment: this is not /quite/ right, `;` starts the next command as soon as the first one ended. `&` actually puts the command to the background.

just try this: `echo foo & echo bar & echo test &`

Comment: @Finkregh, of course. Nobody doubts that. I just meant they both separate commands (from a syntax point of view) with no implications on how they are run.

Comment: It's not quite what was asked, since the question specified issuing a "single command". Neither is my answer, as it too is a series of commands, but it has at least one semantic of a single command in that output is concatenated, can be redirected, etc.

Comment: "Multiple commands with a single command" seems to be an oxymoron, though - what does that mean? If this is for something like `sudo` so you could enter the password only once, wrap then in `bash -c` or similar.

Answer (score 12):

The bash manpage section titled [Compound Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping) has two options that would work, list and group commands.

A group command is a series of commands enclosed in curly braces `{}`. A list is the same, enclosed in parentheses `()`. Both can be used to background multiple commands within, and finally to background the entire collection as a set. The list construct executes commands in a subshell, so variable assignments are not preserved.

To execute a group of commands:

```
{ command1 & command2 & } &
```

You can also execute your commands in a list (subshell):

```
( command1 & command2 ) &
```

Comment: You're welcome. I added the link to the manual. Note that the list `()` syntax executes the enclosed commands in a subshell, so variables are not preserved within.

Answer (score 3):

another way:

```
$(command1 &) && command2 &
```

Comment: No, it will run first command then after finish first then it will run another command

Comment: you used `&&` in your question, it means at first run a command then if run successfuly, run next command.if you don't consider it, you can run `command1 & ; command2 & ;`

Comment: first command successfully goes in bg,  or run using `;` no issue with that