# Running multiple nohup commands in background

Tags: shell, process, background-process, nohup

Got two commands cmd1 and cmd2. Of the two, cmd2 takes longer to finish. Need to run cmd2 and then cmd1.

Tried to run them  in following way:

```
bash$ (nohup ./cmd2>result2 &) && nohup ./cmd1>result1 &
```

or

```
bash$ (nohup ./cmd2>result2 &) ; nohup ./cmd1>result1 &
```

But both time I can see cmd1 is not waiting for cmd2 to finish and result1 gets filled.

How to make cmd1 run after cmd2  when both should be  nohup  process and run in background?

Comment: This question is already asked http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/how-can-one-run-multiple-programs-in-the-background-with-single-command

Comment: The question in the http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/how-can-one-run-multiple-programs-in-the-background-with-single-command is slightly different as I wanted to maintain my order of execution . Please correct me if I am wrong in understanding the other question.

Answer (score 15):

You made both `cmd1` and `cmd2` run in parallel. You said: “Start cmd2 in the background and sever any association with it. Start cmd1 in the background and sever any association with it.” You meant: “Start cmd2 in the background; when it's complete, start cmd1 (also in the background).” Since there is no longer any association with the background task, you need to devise a background task that performs cmd2 then cmd1. This is `cmd2; cmd1` (or rather `cmd2 && cmd1` to run cmd1 only if cmd2 succeeds), and you'll need to tell `nohup` to start a shell running in the background for that.

```
nohup sh -c './cmd2 >result2 && ./cmd1 >result1' &
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine. Yeah, thats what I was thinking , after making the first cmd go to background, it does not affect the second command, which starts even though I wanted it to wait for the first command to finish. I need  to read the manual about sending command to background.

Comment: If I am running the commands on a server and I already submitted one command with `nohup`, if I open a new terminal connection to the server and do the second command with `nohup` will it run both simultaneously?

Comment: @M.O. Yes. `nohup` has no effect on what can run concurrently. It only affects whether the program risks getting killed when its terminal disappears.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind not using nohup:

```
{ command1 >result1 2>&1 && command2 >result2 2>&1 ; } & disown
```

Comment: Will check that out. But currently will go with answer from Giles where the command is wrapped with sh. Thanks anyway

Comment: This is a bad idea.  When user logout from the console,  it will kill the session.

Comment: @mootmoot this works as intended, check this for yourself; commands won't receive SIGHUP when parent shell exits.

Comment: Yes, it is shell safe if you run the command using crond/crontab. But it is not pty/xterm/ssh safe.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and

Answer (score 2):

Simply use :

```
nohup ./cmd2>result2 & nohup ./cmd1>result1 & nohup ./cmd3>result3 &
```

Comment: While running the multiple command is fine, I wanted to maintain the exact order of execution i.e. cmd2 first and then cmd1 and it is not happening with the above command. thanks

Answer (score 1):

let us know what exactly you are doing with cmd2 and cmd1 . It depend upon type of task and output you want from your command.
If you are facing issue with hitting two times enter key with command then it can be figure out by my this [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84TPF.jpg)

you can go by this way also

```
nohup `cmd2 && ccmd1` > Output.out 2> Error.err < /dev/null &
```

See the below given screenshot, Here I am using 3 commands and all are executing one by one serially. I used backticks for this task.
In screenshot you can also observe the date time stamp. sleep command has 60 seconds,hence after 60 seconds my next command is run successfully.
I used jobs command to check is any command still running at background. Here no. of jobs you can see is 1 .

[image: nohup-multiple-command]

This screenshot is available in this [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/48192853@N02/9289020419/) also,if it is not visible